# Calculate profit per single strategy

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to calculate the profit per individual strategy within the same Pinescript script. I am using the following code to calculate the performance:

```
calcolo_performance_backtest(comment) =>
    trade_comment = strategy.closedtrades.entry_comment(strategy.closedtrades - 1)
    net_profit = 0.0
    if trade_comment == comment
        net_profit := strategy.closedtrades.profit(strategy.closedtrades - 1)
    net_profit
```

And this function is called every time a trade is closed:

```
if conditionExit and strategy.opentrades != 0 
    strategy.close("trigger_1_s", comment="Uscita S #1")
    net_profit_trigger1_s += calcolo_performance_backtest("Entrata S #1")
```

At the end I print all data in a table:

```
if barstate.islastconfirmedhistory or barstate.isrealtime
    table.cell(tbl, 0, 0, "Strategy",  bgcolor = #aaaaaa)
    table.cell(tbl, 1, 0, "Net Profit", bgcolor = #aaaaaa)
     
    table.cell(tbl, 0, 1, "Strategy 1",  bgcolor = color.green)
    table.cell(tbl, 1, 1, str.tostring(net_profit_trigger1_l,  "#.##"), bgcolor = color.red)

    table.cell(tbl, 0, 2, "Strategy 2",  bgcolor = color.green)
    table.cell(tbl, 1, 2, str.tostring(net_profit_trigger1_s, "#.##"), bgcolor = color.red)
```

The calculation is wrong: it doesn't calculate the last but the penultimate:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to recieve cum profit for the last X trades, here is solution

```
//@version=5
strategy("`")

// Strategy calls to enter long trades every 15 bars and exit long trades every 20 bars.
if bar_index % 15 == 0
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
if bar_index % 20 == 0
    strategy.close("Long")

// // create array that will contain cumProfit, with the size determinited by the current amount of trades in the CumProfit() function 
closedtradesCumProfArr = array.new<float>(0)

closedtradesCumProfArrGet(int i) =>
  array.get(closedtradesCumProfArr, i)

CumProfit() =>
    sumGrossProfit = 0.0
    for tradeNo = 0 to strategy.closedtrades - 1
        sumGrossProfit += strategy.closedtrades.profit(tradeNo) - strategy.closedtrades.commission(tradeNo)
        array.push(closedtradesCumProfArr, sumGrossProfit)
   
var tbl = table.new(position.top_right, 3, 4, color.orange, border_width = 1)

if barstate.islastconfirmedhistory or barstate.isrealtime
    // call it on a last bar for efficiency
    CumProfit()

    table.cell(tbl, 0, 0, "Strategy",  bgcolor = #aaaaaa)
    table.cell(tbl, 1, 0, "Net Profit", bgcolor = #aaaaaa)
     
    table.cell(tbl, 0, 1, "Strategy 1",  bgcolor = color.green)
    table.cell(tbl, 1, 1, str.tostring(closedtradesCumProfArrGet(strategy.closedtrades - 1)))

    table.cell(tbl, 0, 2, "Strategy 2",  bgcolor = color.green)
    table.cell(tbl, 1, 2,str.tostring(closedtradesCumProfArrGet(strategy.closedtrades - 2)))
```